# How to parse a string in Java? Is there anything similar to Python's re.finditer()?

Tags: java, python, regex, parsing

I have an input string with a very simple pattern - capital letter, integer, capital letter, integer, ...  and I would like to separate each capital letter and each integer. I can't figure out the best way to do this in Java.

I have tried regexp using Pattern and Matcher, then StringTokenizer, but still without success.

This is what I want to do, shown in Python:

```
for token in re.finditer( "([A-Z])(\d*)", inputString):
      print token.group(1)
      print token.group(2)
```

For input "A12R5F28" the result would be:

```
A

12

R

5

F

28
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use regex API in Java and achieve the same functionality:

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z])(\d+)")
Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher("A12R5F28");
while (myMatcher.find()) {
      // Do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: your RE has Unbalanced Parentheses.)

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly, my problem was that I was using myMatcher.matches() instead of myMatcher.find()

Comment: Since the integer part is required, I would change `\d*` (0 or more digits) to `\d+` (1 or more digits).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Ravi's Answer....

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z])(\\d+)");
Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher("A12R5F28");
while (myMatcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(myMatcher.group(1) + "\n" + myMatcher.group(2));
}
```